# Read large file into byte array and encode it to ToBase64String

Tags: c#, base64, filereader

I have implemented POC to read entire file content into Byte[] array. I am now succeeded to read files whose size below 100MB, when I load file whose size more than 100MB then it is throwing

> Convert.ToBase64String(mybytearray)   Cannot obtain value of the
>   local variable or argument because there is not enough memory
>   available.

Below is my code that I have tried to read content from file to Byte array

```
var sFile = fileName;
var mybytearray = File.ReadAllBytes(sFile);

var binaryModel = new BinaryModel
{
    fileName = binaryFile.FileName,
    binaryData = Convert.ToBase64String(mybytearray),
    filePath = string.Empty
};
```

My model class is as below

```
public class BinaryModel
{
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string binaryData { get; set; }
    public string filePath { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting "Convert.ToBase64String(mybytearray) Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because there is not enough memory available." this error at Convert.ToBase64String(mybytearray).

Is there anything which I need to take care to prevent this error?

*Note: I do not want to add line breaks to my file content*

Comment: Under usual circumstances loading and encoding 100mb should not cause any issues at all, there is something else going on - I think you need to add some more details including the full stack trace & exception message, there are no google hits for the one you have posted.

Comment: By default, the max size of an object is 2GB so probably as said by @AlexK. the problem is not the declaration of a 100MB array

Comment: I think this is going to be pretty infeasible to pull off.  How big is your biggest file?  For example, if you have a 500 MB file, you are talking a string of around 699,050,660 characters long.  Since each character is 2 bytes you are talking 1.3 GB of memory just to hold this string.

Comment: @AlexK. - It is not the array for the file, I am guessing the issue lies in converting that binary stream to a Base64 encoded string. The ratio is basically 8/6 or roughly 1.3 increase in your "array" length, but bear in mind that since these are now `char`s in the array, we are doubling the data requirement.  So a 500 MB file becomes a 1.3 GB string array. A 200 MB file is going to be a string of about 530 MB.

Comment: @Vijay - Is it possible for you to do this as a stream, read it and write it out to a file or something or is your requirement to hold that string in memory (as part of `BinaryModel`). I don't think there is going to be any way for you to keep that whole string in memory.  As you can see from the suggested answers, each is showing writing this data directly back out to a file.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the quick reply however as you all saying is correct the problem is not reading file content into bytes, but problem comes when I try to convert these bytes to Base64 and passing this to Model

at line binaryData = Convert.ToBase64String(mybytearray)  I got error

Comment: @pstrjds you got my problem in your second and third comment, I want to hold string in memory and pass it over HTTP. So in my requirement I do not have to write these string data to file in the same application.

Comment: @Vijay - Then the answer is basically you can't, without dividing it and sending it in chunks. There really isn't another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use two filestreams - one to read the large file, one to write the result back out.

So in chunks you would convert to base 64 ... then convert the resulting string to bytes ... and write.

```
    private static void ConvertLargeFileToBase64()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (var fsIn = new FileStream("D:\\in.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (var fsOut = new FileStream("D:\\out.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    // convert to base 64 and convert to bytes for writing back to file
                    var b64 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(buffer));

                    // write to the output filestream
                    fsOut.Write(b64, 0, read);
                }

                fsOut.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To save memory you can convert stream of bytes in 3-packs. Every three bytes produce 4 bytes in Base64. You don't need whole file in memory at once.

Here is pseudocode:

```
Repeat
1. Try to read max 3 bytes from stream
2. Convert to base64, write to output stream
```

And simple implementation:

```
using (var inStream = File.OpenRead("E:\\Temp\\File.xml"))
using (var outStream = File.CreateText("E:\\Temp\\File.base64"))
{
    var buffer = new byte[3];
    int read;
    while ((read = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, 3)) > 0)
    {
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer, 0, read);
        outStream.Write(base64);
    }
}
```

Hint: every multiply of 3 is valid. Higher - more memory, better performance, lower - less memory, worse performance.

**Additional info:**

File stream is an example. As a result stream use `[HttpContext].Response.OutputStream` and write directly to it. Processing hundreds of megabytes in one chunk will kill you and your server.

Think about total memory requirements. 100MB in string, leads to 133 MB in byte array, since you wrote about model I expect copy of this 133 MB in response. And remember it's just a simple request. A few such requests could drain your memory.